# Does artisan config:cache and other optimization affect my database (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Because everytime we deploy our project and run php artisan optimization command like config:cache my database goes updating itself like my status column in database getting inactive or nulls.

[image: My Logs in database]

Comment: And when you deploy without the `config:cache` command, does it then also affect the status columns?

Comment: we can't immediately see it, if it's affected because we have to use config:cache for the path in able to run the application.

Comment: what part of the application relies on `config:cache` exactly?

Comment: Paths and variables to run application. we deploying it from windows to linux

Comment: But why are they not present without `config:cache`? when laravel caches the config it caches what is currently loaded in the config object, so technically your paths and variables should still be in there?